# Wrong __DIR__ magic constant value

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, composer-php

I've been trying to install a web application which is built using the Laravel framework. The application is hosted as a GIT repository.

Here is a detailed description of my problem to clarify how I'm facing it.

For the first time I cloned the repository in the following path:

> /var/www/app.example.com/script/

Then created a symbolic link to it's `public` directory like this to follow my server's `nginx` routing convention:

```
ln -s /var/www/app.example.com/script/public /var/www/app.example.com/public_html
```

But I decided to move everything out of the `script` directory to one upper level and this is where my problem started.
I moved the Laravel installation to `/var/www/app.example.com/` and made nginx to directly load its `public` directory as the root path.

Now the problem is every time I try to load the application it's trying to read the files from their previous location:

> Warning:
>   require(/var/www/app.example.com/script/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/app.example.com/public/index.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/app.example.com/script/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/app.example.com/public/index.php on line 21

Notes to keep in mind:

- I've used composer to install all the dependencies

  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  php composer.phar install
- I'm using `nginx` as my web server
- I've tried removing everything (including `~/.composer`) and start all over again to no avail.
- I have even tried to move the whole project into a new root directory
- It seems the problem is with `__DIR__` magic constant since it contains the wrong path
- Weirdly enough if I echo `__DIR__` it prints the correct path but in the next line in which it's used it has the incorrect old path

> I hope I have been clear enough in my description to avoid any confusion and possible down-votes.

Comment: _"Then created a symbolic link to it's public"_ Careful with symlinks, you may want to use `realpath(__DIR__)` instead of the magic constant here... Also: is `script/public/../bootstrap/` correct? I mean: is bootstrap indeed on the same level as `public`? Does the actual path look like this: `script/bootstrap/autoload.php`? And lastly: Why aren't you simply using composers' autoloader?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Is editing the Laravel's core files a reasonable thing to do? And yes they are on the same level. The actual path used to look like `script/bootstrap/autoload.php` but now they are inside a completely different path. And lastly I am using the composer's autoloader.

Comment: If they're in a completely different path, use `realpath(__DIR__)` for starters (it resolves the symlink), and, perhaps best of all: add the current path to the [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php), best prepend it: `$paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());  array_unshift($thePath, $paths); set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));` or something like that...

Comment: Did you solve it? I have similar problem when `__DIR__` shows path to different directory (to other domain on server) and I have no idea how to solve it (`realpath(__DIR__)` works, but there is also used `__DIR__` in vendor files so error will just move to other file and line). I don't see any simlinks there and I really don't know why it doesn't show normal path.

Comment: @caburt unfortunately not. had to switch servers.

Comment: For future strangers - in my case, the reason was OPcache bug/feature that was loading file from different domain on the same server because it has similar directory structure and file names. Works for me only by turning off OPcache https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67481

Answer (score 0):

So i could be completly wrong here, but is there a configuration file where it might have saved it? Or is there still something left in the `script` directory that can mabey cause this? As when the `__DIR__` outputs the right value, then it should in the other code too.

Comment: The `script` directory is now completely removed and the project files are cloned inside a completely different and independent path.